# How to sign in using Firebase, C# Visual Studio WINFORMS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase in Android Studio and now I'm trying to use it in Visual Studio. I learned how to register a new user in Firebase Authentification but I struggle with signing in.

How I register:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
[...]
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken;
UserRecordArgs user = new UserRecordArgs();
user.Email = email;
user.Password = pw;
try
{
    UserRecord x = await firebaseAuth.CreateUserAsync(user, cancellationToken);
    MessageBox.Show("Account created! You can login now.");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong! Try later.");
}
```

I can't find a function equivalent with signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use third party library [FirebaseAuthentication.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet)

```
    public async Task<bool> SignIn(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            FirebaseAuthProvider mAuthProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("YourFirebaseApiKey"));

            mAuthLink = await mAuthProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(
                  "https://yourfirebasesite.firebaseio.com",
                  new FirebaseOptions
                  {
                      AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(mAuthLink.FirebaseToken)

                  });

            // Process user info from mAuthLink
            Properties.Settings.Default.email_txt = mAuthLink.User.Email;
            Properties.Settings.Default.token_txt = mAuthLink.FirebaseToken;
            Properties.Settings.Default.refresh_token_txt = mAuthLink.RefreshToken;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

For more information about how to use this library, I created a [Account Manager](https://gist.github.com/zhenyuan0502/653ddaca0a1724c3e4aa2ecd8899b793) to use and save all logging information to `Properties.Settings`

Because it's a Singleton so it's easy to handle User Account.

```
AccountManager.GetInstance().SignIn("email","password");
AccountManager.GetInstance().SignOut();
AccountManager.GetInstance().SignUp("email", "password");
AccountManager.GetInstance().IsSignOut; // Check it's signout yet?
```

Comment: I will try! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi! I tried using it and it doesn't work. It always ends up on catch and I can't figure out why... Is there anything else I should do besides this code?

Comment: @user11815194 ok so you do `catch(Exception ex)`, give me `ex.ToString()` info

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother you again. How do you log out & how do you see if you are logged in and the info of the user you are currently logged in to using this library?

Comment: @user11815194 You could retrieve information from `mAuthLink.User`. To check user whether is keeping logged, use this event  `mAuthLink.FirebaseAuthRefreshed` to get `e.FirebaseAuth.FirebaseToken` and `e.FirebaseAuth.RefreshToken`. As it's logged, it still get them. Once you would like to logout, simply remove their token. Since project owner didn't guide more information so I write a [AccountManager](https://gist.github.com/zhenyuan0502/653ddaca0a1724c3e4aa2ecd8899b793) for myself. I updated to my post.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!

Comment: HI! It's me, again, sorry... Is it possible to delete a user from auth table knowing its email?

Comment: I've checked the library and it seems not support delete a user. But basically you could go to the web of firebase manager to delete it manual.